# In node-js: app.render('filename') generating error on chrome of internal server error.

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to render the profile.ejs page, but it show the error of "Internal server error".

Status Code:500 Internal Server Error.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/',function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/profile/:id',function(req, res){
  res.render('profile');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: So what does your server log say?

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing data to ejs (as you probably are, since this is a user profile page), you need to include an object as the second argument to the render function.

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;
    models.users.findOne({where: {id: userId}}).then(function(user){
        res.render('profile', {
            username: user.dataValues.userName,
        });
    })
}
```

Indeed, when I ran my own example without passing an object (or passing an empty object to a view that had ejs data in it), I got a 500 error as well.

For any variables that appear in your ejs, such as

```
<div>
    Welcome, <%= username %>
</div>
```

the values of those variables need to be set in that response object.